# Custom Excerpt Length

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
/**
* Change the length of excerpt.
*
* @param int $length The number of words. Default 55.
* @return int New excerpt length.
*/
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {

    return 20; // number of words. Default is 55.
}
```

This function returns 20 words on the excerpt on my blog post. How can I customize this that instead of 20 words, it will return the first paragraph of my post.

Comment: So how will you decide for _first paragraph_ ?

Comment: @nice_dev probably checking for the first period.

Comment: `echo substr('Test. Xyz.',0,strpos('Test. Xyz.','.') + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following function in functions.php file and it will return the first paragraph of post.

```
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'erginous_custom_excerpt', 10, 2 );

function erginous_custom_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt) {
    if( ! $raw_excerpt ) {
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        $text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );
    }
    return $text;
}
```

This functions add a filter to modify the wp_trim_excerpt returned value by checking for the manual excerpt.

Comment: Does exactly what I need. How do I modify this if I want it to be just the first sentence?

Comment: For sentence use the following function in functions.php  @juscuizonn 

`function erginous_first_sentence( $string ) {
 
    $sentence = preg_split( '/(\.|!|\?)\s/', $string, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
    return $sentence['0'] . $sentence['1'];
 
} add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'erginous_first_sentence', 10, 1 );`